# I need a delay between opening a set amount of tabs from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, delay

I need to make 3 new tabs in my chrome extension with a delay of a couple seconds between each of the tabs creation, but when I use the `chrome.tabs.create` in a for loop `for(i=0;i<3;i++)` with the `setTimeout(function()` like so

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    setTimeout(function() {
    search();
}, 5000);
```

It just waits for the Timeout to finish and then opens all 3 tabs at once. I have looked at [Chrome extension: open tabs with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734483/chrome-extension-open-tabs-with-delay) but it is a different situation.

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're telling the browser to open all three tabs after 5 seconds.

If you'd like them to open one after another, you'd have to multiply the timeout by your iterator (+1, unless you want the first tab to open immediately), like so:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    setTimeout(function() {
       search();
    }, 5000 * (i + 1));
}
```

Comment: That does introduce a delay before the first tab opens but then it doesn't keep going after one tab is made. I don't know if it is a problem with my search function or if the problem is caused by the loop being activated from a button that is then closed. [Code](http://pastebin.com/qRTp60Gq)

Comment: @JoeSchroedl, that's because your `search()` function executes too long, `setTimeout` means add the task onto the queue after a set number of milliseconds. If the queue is empty, then the code is executed immediately; if the queue is not empty (your search() function is still running), the code must wait its turn.

Comment: That may be so but what would take up so much of the queue that the code wouldn't continue? I have tried simpler functions inside the loop and all of them only happen once.